# Silverstripe NGINX Tiny MCE editor not loading

Tags: nginx

I've got Silverstripe CMS running under NGINX. Everything is working, until I tried modifying a page in the CMS. The Tiny MCE editor is not working for some reason. tiny_mce_gzip.php is downloaded properly (200), but I see the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined" in my console.

This is my NGINX config file for the Silverstripe CMS:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri @silverstripe;
    }

    location @silverstripe {
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 65k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/framework/main.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /framework/main.php;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING url=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 65k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    }

    # Deny access to silverstripe-cache
    location ~ ^/silverstripe-cache {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to logs
    location ~ ^/logs {
        deny all;
    }

    # Don't execute scripts in the assets folder
    location ^~ /assets/ {
        sendfile on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Deny access to composer
    location ~ ^/(vendor|composer.json|composer.lock) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to yaml files
    location ~ \.yml$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to template files
    location ~ \.ss$ {
        satisfy any;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # CMS & Framework .htaccess rules
    location ~ ^/(cms|framework|mysite)/.*\.(php|php[345]|phtml|inc)$ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/(cms|framework)/silverstripe_version$ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/framework/.*(main|static-main|rpc|tiny_mce_gzip)\.php$ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Deny access to all dot files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
```

}

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wmk in #silverstripe on IRC came with the solution to disable GZIP:

Put this in "mysite/_config/config.yml" HtmlEditorField: use_gzip: false

And flush the Silverstripe cache with "?flush=all". And you've got your editor back :-)